# Angular Karma post has unexpected JSON

Tags: angularjs, json, karma-jasmine

I have the following karma test. But I get the error "EXPECTED: {"data":{"form_field_17":"None Required","title":"Mr","firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","email":"john@gmail.com","mobile":"1114269874","registration":"123","form_field_15":"Test","pref_date":"2016-08-30T02:13:00.000Z"},"formId":4}
GOT:      {"data":"{\"form_field_17\":\"None Required\",\"title\":\"Mr\",\"firstName\":\"John\",\"lastName\":\"Doe\",\"email\":\"john@gmail.com\",\"mobile\":\"1114269874\",\"registration\":\"123\",\"form_field_15\":\"Test\",\"pref_date\":\"30/08/2016 12:13 PM\"}","formId":4}

Why does my JSON object have backslashes and my pref_date has changed format?

```
describe('when submitting a form', function () {
        it('should be successful', function () {
            var d = {
                form_field_17: "None Required",
                title: "Mr",
                firstName: "John",
                lastName: "Doe",
                email: "john@gmail.com",
                mobile: "1114269874",
                registration: "123",
                form_field_15: "Test",
                pref_date: "2016-08-30T02:13:00.000Z"
            };

            $httpBackend.expect('POST', '/DynamicForm/SubmitForm/', { data: d, formId: 4})
                .respond(200, "[{ success : 'true', data : 'true' }]");

            DynamicFormFactory.SubmitForm(d, 4)
              .then(function (data) {
                  expect(data.success).toBeTruthy();
              });

            $httpBackend.flush();

            $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingExpectation();
            $httpBackend.verifyNoOutstandingRequest();
        });
    });
```

Comment: What you have done is compare some JSON ` {"data":{...` with the result which is a string containing JSON.  `{"data":"{...`   If the response is a string and not a JSON object perhaps you need to eval it before comparing.

Comment: How do I do that?